# Easiest way to see if SQL field changed False to True for certain users over time?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Table with Users,Date, and IS_MEMBER.

Certain users went from IS_MEMBER False -> True.

I want to make a new field to identify these users (set BECAME_MEMBER to True).

I don't want this new field set to True for users who stopped becoming members, already were members, or any other behavior besides simply becoming and staying members at any Date.

Simplified example, though real table is much larger:

```
Users|Date|IS_MEMBER
1111|2020-01-01|FALSE
1111|2020-07-10|FALSE
1111|2020-11-20|FALSE
2222|2020-01-01|FALSE
2222|2020-07-10|TRUE
2222|2020-11-20|FALSE
3333|2020-01-01|FALSE
3333|2020-07-10|TRUE
3333|2020-11-20|TRUE
4444|2020-01-01|TRUE
4444|2020-07-10|TRUE
4444|2020-11-20|TRUE
```

Desired result:

```
Users|Date|IS_MEMBER|BECAME_MEMBER
1111|2020-01-01|FALSE|FALSE
1111|2020-07-10|FALSE|FALSE
1111|2020-11-20|FALSE|FALSE
2222|2020-01-01|FALSE|FALSE
2222|2020-07-10|TRUE|FALSE
2222|2020-11-20|FALSE|FALSE
3333|2020-01-01|FALSE|TRUE
3333|2020-07-10|TRUE|TRUE
3333|2020-11-20|TRUE|TRUE
4444|2020-01-01|TRUE|FALSE
4444|2020-07-10|TRUE|FALSE
4444|2020-11-20|TRUE|FALSE
```

What is the best way to create a SQL statement for this? I'm using SnowSQL but any RDMS language is ok for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions to flag the first membership:

```
select t.*,
    (is_member and (min(date) over(partition by users, member) = date)) as became_member
from mytable t
```

This assumes that `is_member` is of `boolean` datatype.

Comment: So sorry about that. I added a fourth member to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data suggests that you want to know if they are currently a member:

```
select t.*,
       (max(case when is_member then date end) over (partition by users) =
        max(date) over (partition by users)
       ) as is_currently_member
from t;
```

You have no examples where all the rows are `true` for a member.  But if you didn't want those to count, you can check that some false value exists:

```
select t.*,
       (sum( case when not is_member then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by user) > 0 and
        max(case when is_member then date end) over (partition by user) =
        max(date) over (partition by user)
       ) as is_currently_member
from t;
```

Comment: So sorry about that. I added a fourth member to clarify.

Comment: @MarkMcGown . . . That is what the second query handles.